# React-Semantic-UI, Accordion, title in label. "Inline" within arrow icon

Tags: css, semantic-ui

#### Testcase

https://codesandbox.io/s/q305wzzw46

#### Expected Result

Label "inline" within "arrow" icon.

#### Actual Result

[image]

#### Version

React-Semantic-UI 0.77.2

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: I need a way to make the long label like the short one. Do you see the screen picture?

Comment: You need to modify the semantic ui css. There's .ui.accordion .title:not(.ui) selector, give it `display: flex` and from there you can work on the styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**override** the semantic-UI CSS like this :

```
.ui.accordion .title:not(.ui){
  display: flex;
}
```

*to act labels like boxes*

```
.ui.accordion .title .dropdown.icon{
   display: inline-flex; 
   flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

*to organize icons vertically*

Comment: Why the code in `.ui.accordion .title .dropdown.icon{`? I don't understand why...

Comment: @JohnSam well did you try what it does?

Comment: yes but it does nothing. Can you fork my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/q305wzzw46?

Comment: @JohnSam if u use this part this will arrange the icons in one vertical line . i test it on your codesandbox